# unable to import requests after installing in virtual environment python 2.7 pycharm

Tags: python, import, pip, python-requests, virtualenv

so I navigate to my virtual environment.

Activate it

do `pip install requests`

it installs

i go to a file and then `import requests`

then get this error:

```
No module named request less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.
```

i did pip install again just to see and I get this:

```
pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
```

Im using pycharm and in a django project. I dont think either of those matter but just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that my pycharm software was set to the global install of python not my virtual env instance. I had to set up pycharm to use that env instance, by following the instructions here:

http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/configure-pycharm-to-use-virtualenv/